# how to pivot complex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe shown in below.

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'contract1' :["A", "B", "C", "D", "B"],
           'contract2' :["C", "A", np.nan, "A", np.nan],
           'contract3' :[np.nan, "C", np.nan, np.nan, np.nan] })
df

ID        contract1   contract2   contract3    
1             A           C         nan
2             B           A          C
3             C          nan        nan
4             D           A         nan
5             B          nan        nan
```

I would like the flag result like this;

```
ID     A     B     C      D
1      1     0     1      0
2      1     1     1      0 
3      0     0     1      0
4      1     0     0      1
5      0     1     0      0
```

This flag table show whether each ID have a each contract. 
Maybe pivot is available,but I couldn't handle this kind of complex dataframe...
Can I ask how to transform ?

Comment: Have a look at pd.get_dummies

Comment: thank you for reply. it is very helpful. I just look over ref!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Faster implementation would be to use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) in conjunction with [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) as shown:

```
pd.melt(df, id_vars=['ID']).set_index('ID')['value']        \
                           .str.get_dummies()               \
                           .groupby(level=0)                \
                           .agg(np.sum)

    A  B  C  D
ID            
1   1  0  1  0
2   1  1  1  0
3   0  0  1  0
4   1  0  0  1
5   0  1  0  0
```

Comment: thank you !  I have one question. why you apply .agg(np.sum) method ?

Comment: The reason is that when you melt the dataframe, you get all your column values under a single column, `value` to which the indicator variables are encoded by `get_dummies`. So, 15 entries in total[5 per column]. You need to aggregate on the common groupby level, `ID`. Hence, the need for `agg(np.sum)`. Another reason is for improving performance. It is almost twice as fast as using `sum` on the `grouped` object. Btw, my method is the fastest among the lot ;)

Comment: I see. I wondered why you didn't apply `sum()`. I learned that for the first time. that the `agg(np.sum)` is faster than `sum()`...  I leaned alot ! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can melt your original data frame to long format and then use `crosstab()` on the ID and value column:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = df.set_index('ID').stack().rename("Type").reset_index()    
pd.crosstab(df1.ID, df1.Type)

# Type  A   B   C   D
#   ID              
#   1   1   0   1   0
#   2   1   1   1   0
#   3   0   0   1   0
#   4   1   0   0   1
#   5   0   1   0   0
```

Comment: thank you for early reply! I have not used the crosstab() . it is very usefull!

Answer (score 1):

We could also do this with `melt/pivot_table`

```
res = pd.melt(df, id_vars = ['ID'], value_vars = ['contract1', 
       'contract2', 'contract3']).pivot_table(index = 'ID', 
          columns = 'value', fill_value = 0, aggfunc=len)
print(res)
#    variable         
#value        A  B  C  D
#ID                     
#1            1  0  1  0
#2            1  1  1  0
#3            0  0  1  0
#4            1  0  0  1
#5            0  1  0  0
```

#### data

```
import pandas as pd;
import numpy as np;
df =pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'contract1' :["A", "B", "C", "D", "B"],
           'contract2' :["C", "A", np.nan, "A", np.nan],
           'contract3' :[np.nan, "C", np.nan, np.nan, np.nan] })
df
```

Comment: thank you for providing data.  melt and pivot_table is very applicable...I can learn a lot.   I just edited my question. and I cited your data code ! thank you very much !

Comment: sorry  I couldnt understand the option  `aggfunc = len`   
If I remember correctly,the function len  returns the length of string. why you set this option?

Comment: @MiyashitaHikaru  The `melt` step returns three column dataset, which when pivoted with `pivot_table` for the column 'value' the `len` (length) returns the length of each element in 'value'.  As there are no dupes, it returns 1 and `fill_value` for combinations that doesn't exist to `0`