# How to pivot a set of multiple columns into a set of flagged values through DataFrame while not wanting to pivot all columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot, melt

So, I have an advanced pivot question. Consider the following data frame

```
dfa = pandas.DataFrame([["g1","15","Annie","Bard"], ["g2","18","Lux","Annie"], ["g3","15","Olaf","Twitch"]], columns=["gameId", "duration", "Champ1", "Champ2"])
```

This gives the output:

[image]

By applying the logic in the following stack overflow question, [how to pivot complex dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176882/how-to-pivot-complex-dataframe) ,  I get

```
pandas.melt(dfa, id_vars=['gameId']) \
    .set_index('gameId')['value'] \
    .str.get_dummies() \
    .groupby(level=0) \
    .agg(np.sum)
```

[image]

However, I don't want to pivot the duration column and so I change my code and add 'value_vars'

```
pandas.melt(dfa, id_vars=['gameId'], value_vars = ['Champ1','Champ2']) \
    .set_index('gameId')['value'] \
    .str.get_dummies() \
    .groupby(level=0) \
    .agg(np.sum)
```

[image]

And now I lose the duration column. This columns isn't an index as it isn't unique, but I don't want to pivot it. I've tried all combinations of addit it to 'id_vars' or 'set_index()', but it doesn't seem to work.

Thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add column `duration` to `id_vars`, then to `set_index` and last `groupby` by both levels in `Multiindex` as follows:

```
a = pd.melt(dfa, id_vars=['gameId', 'duration']) \
    .set_index(['gameId', 'duration'])['value'] \
    .str.get_dummies()
    .sum(level=[0,1])
print (a)
                 Annie  Bard  Lux  Olaf  Twitch
gameId duration                                
g1     15            1     1    0     0       0
g2     18            1     0    1     0       0
g3     15            0     0    0     1       1
```

What is same as:

```
a = pd.melt(dfa, id_vars=['gameId', 'duration']) \
    .set_index(['gameId', 'duration'])['value'] \
    .str.get_dummies() \
    .groupby(level=[0,1]) \
    .sum()
print (a)
                 Annie  Bard  Lux  Olaf  Twitch
gameId duration                                
g1     15            1     1    0     0       0
g2     18            1     0    1     0       0
g3     15            0     0    0     1       1
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. I tried 'gameId', 'duration', but didn't have it in a list nor did I have the levels in the group by.

Comment: You are welcome. Btw, if need always `0`, `1` output need `max`, not `sum`.

Comment: So, how would i query by duration = 15? I can query by gameId = g1 with a.loc[:'g1'], but a.loc[:15] or a.loc[:'15'] doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try `a.xs(15, level=1)`

Comment: And check it - [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html)